# Split lines at vertices based on length and angle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting

I have polyline data that represents watermains. I want to break polyline features up based on some point layers to input into another software package - the points represent valves, fittings, etc.  Currently a single polyline feature may have several point features on it, as well as some bends ranging from minor (a few degrees) to signficant (up to 90 degrees).

Ideally I want to break the polyline based on criteria such as:

1. Where a bend is greater than say 5 degrees
2. Where the length is greater that say 100m
3. Based on points in a specific layer

I tried to utilise "Split by Points" command but where the polylines had bends the new line would be straight through.  I tried this with various settings but couldnt achieve a good split.

I tried "V.split" with the "No of Vertex" set to 2 but this broke the lines at every vertex (eg on curves or poorly digitised sections). I then run "Split by Points" but this generated a huge number of short lines.  I had a similar result with "Explode" command.

I tried "Extract Vertices" command but couldnt figure out a way to weed out the points that were too close or on small bends.

I also couldnt find a plug in to achieve what I need.

Is there an alternate method to achieve this that I might have missed.

Comment: Possible using pyqgis. But your question is too broad. For example over which distance do you want to measure the 5 degrees? Image the line looking like a long curve? Over a long distance the bend will exceed 5 but not in individual vertices? I think you should add a reproducable line to your question (for example vertex coords as text) and show exactly how it should be split